# React/MaterialUI - TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my mapping function initially worked until a few seconds ago, now I keep getting the error originally stated in the title. How can I fix this for my case below?

```
 export default function Graph()
 {
     const { slug } = useParams();
     const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axiosInstance.get('bucket/' + slug + '/').then((res) => {
            setData(res.data);
            console.log(res.data.stock_list);
        });
     }, [setData, slug]);

    

     return (
         <Container>
             <Grid>
             <Paper>
                 <List dense component="div" role="list">
                 {data.stock_list.map((value) => {
                    return (
                        <ListItem role="listitem">
                            {value}
                        </ListItem>
                    );
                    })}
                </List> 
             </Paper>
             </Grid>
         </Container>
    ); 
 }
```

Comment: As a side note, be careful with the useEffect array dependency (`[setData, slug]`). I'm guessing you only need to trigger the axios call when the slug changes and putting setData there could trigger additional executions

Comment: Hi Fabio, what other additional unexcepted executions could occur ?

Comment: Actually setData doesn't change much now that I think about it. I just thought as only slug should trigger the change you should only include that one, but at a practical level there's no need to change anything :)

Comment: Okay thank you for the clarification, always looking to learn more what I don't know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data.stock_list is undefined on the first render because you are initializing it to []. You could change to

```
    const [data, setData] = useState(); 
    ...
    {
      data?.stock_list?.map(value => <ListItem role="listitem">{value}</ListItem>)
    }
```

That way it won't continue unless data.stock_list is defined.

Comment: Thank you so much :)